# You don't have permission to access /cacti/index.php on this server

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, snmp, cacti

in cacti.conf I tried to edit the default context from localhost to 0.0.0.0 (and everything in between).
Now I only have

```
Alias /cacti /usr/share/cacti
<Directory /usr/share/cacti/>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 0.0.0.0
</Directory>
```

in /etc/httpd/conf.d/cacti.conf. (also tried 192.168.0.0/24 and many others)

I have also tried chown -R apache:apache /usr/share/cacti  and 0:0 and cacti:cacti of the same folder.
Always the same permissions error.

I cannot log in locally, server is many many miles away with zero desktop.

Comment: Change the alias line to alias /cacti/ /usr/share/cacti and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation on Apache....The directives you state will always result in denial..reasons:

1. Directive order deny,allow analyzes deny directives FIRST then allow directives.
2. Your deny from all directive matches everybody and thus due to #1 nobody gets access.
3. Your 0.0.0.0 IP number will not match everybody, thus your allow statement is not effective.

Try a sequence like the following to replace your three possibly problematic directives.

```
 Order allow,deny
 allow from all
```

Comment: I tried  ->   <Directory /usr/share/cacti/>
        Order Deny,Allow

        Allow from all
</Directory>   <--  same issue  but -->          Order Allow, Deny
  <-- produces a new 'webpage not found', even though structurally speaking the file exist.

Comment: logs are bare..  btw, 0.0.0.0 in the networking world means everybody, why would cacti be any different from cisco or iptables? --> 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 = any network any mask

Comment: I was able to get past the denied issue by modifying the default cacti.conf, though I am still having permissions issues.

http://bpaste.net/show/18ddd5914eb6

Answer (score 0):

I'm using CentOS  and had the same problem. I resolved the issue adding specific IP addresses in config:

First **check the IPs that are allowed**

cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/cacti.conf

```
Alias /cacti /var/www/cacti
<Directory /var/www/cacti>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 172.16.24.0/24
    Allow from 172.22.16.0/24
    Allow from ::1*
```

Then edit the config `nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/cacti.conf`

After adding new network.. **error was gone!**